# Prevent page reloading after jQuery post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I wouldn't ask you if other solutions work, but neither e.preventDefault() nor return false works. When I use prevent default ajax doesn't make post request. $.post also doesn't work. And with return false at the end of submit function doesn't have any affect

Comment: You're going to need to include some JavaScript and HTML for us to have any chance at solving the problem.

Answer (score -2):

just add return to onsubmit and return false to function